# Google Site: listing Parent Domain directory Index

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, pagerank, subdirectory

Currently when we search `site:domain.com` on google we get a return of 3.6 million pages indexed, `About 3,650,000 results (0.31 seconds)`. When we search `site:domain.com/childdirectory` we get 3.8 million pages indexed, `About 3,770,000 results (0.60 seconds)`. How is it possible that the child directory has more pages indexed than the parent? Is each directory's index counted separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `site:` is highly unreliable for counting indexed pages. It is often out of date, incorrect and actual serps is limited to sample data only.  You should opt to use Google Webmaster Tools for a more accurate index count.

Comment: Thanks, is there any documentation on the inaccuracies/out-of-datedness of Google's `site:` functionality? With Google Webmaster Tools we can only get the top level index count, not subdirectories.

Comment: I'm sure your find hundreds to thousands of users with similar problem if you search on Google. Fact is `site:` has been abused over the years and one of the reason only sample data is returned and I can never recall it ever having accurate index count.

Answer (score 0):

No google show results based on users adding their webpage indexes because they are using that kind of different algorithm

Comment: What does this mean?